# Clearing an array

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having a problem on an assignment, I can't clear the array.  Also in my MessageBox when it displays the scores I get a zero as the first number no matter what I do.  I can't figure out what to change so zero is not the first element.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int scoreTotal = 0;
    int scoreCount = 0;
    decimal average = 0;
    int[] scoreTotalArray = new int[1];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (IsValidData())
            {
                Int32 score = Convert.ToInt32(txtScore.Text);
                scoreTotalArray[scoreCount] = score;
                Array.Resize(ref scoreTotalArray, scoreTotalArray.Length + 1);
                scoreTotal += score; //accumulator
                scoreCount++; //counter
                average = scoreTotal / (decimal)scoreCount;//average

                txtScoreCount.Text = scoreCount.ToString();//display in score count txtbox
                txtScoreTotal.Text = scoreTotal.ToString(); //display in score total txtbox
                txtAverage.Text = average.ToString("n2"); //display in average text box

                txtScore.Clear();
                txtScore.Focus();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) //catches all other exceptions
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.GetType().ToString());
        }
    }

    public bool IsValidData()
    {
        return
            IsPresent(txtScore, "Score:") &&
            IsInt32(txtScore, "Score:") &&
            IsWithinRange(txtScore, "Score:", 0, 100);
    }

    public bool IsPresent(TextBox textBox, string name)
    {
        if (textBox.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show(name + " is a required field, please enter a number between 0 and 100.", "Entry Error");
            textBox.Focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool IsInt32(TextBox textBox, string name)
    {
        try
        {
            Convert.ToInt32(textBox.Text);
            return true;
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(name + "must be a number between 0 and 100.", "Entry Error");
            textBox.Focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public bool IsWithinRange(TextBox textBox, string name, decimal min, decimal max)
    {
        decimal number = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox.Text);
        if (number < min || number > max)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(name + " must be between " + min + " and " + max + ".", "Entry Error");
            textBox.Focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void btnDisplayScore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Array.Sort(scoreTotalArray);
        string scoreCountString = "\n";
        for(int i = 0; i < scoreCount; i++)
        scoreCountString += scoreTotalArray [i] + "\n";

        MessageBox.Show(scoreCountString + "\n", "Sorted Scores");
    }

    private void btnClearScores_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtScore.Clear();
        txtScoreTotal.Clear();
        txtScoreCount.Clear();
        txtAverage.Clear();

        txtScore.Focus();
    }
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I need to clear the message box, but also the stored data in it, so if the user clicks the "clear scores" button, then they can start over, and it doesn't just keep adding on to the scores entered previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your int array `scoreTotalArray` is always one element to big. That extra element contains the 0 you want to get rid of ;-)

Clearing the scores can be done by resizing your array to 0.

That said: You should probably consider using a `List` instead of an int array.

Comment: We are not allowed to use a list, we have to use an array, so I'm stuck trying to figure this out.  So where would I put the code to resize it?  It's already in there once, not sure where else it should go

Comment: in `btnClearScores_Click`, you should add: `Array.Resize(ref scoreTotalArray, 0);`
Set `scoreTotal`, `scoreCount` and `average` to `0`.

Replace this: `int[] scoreTotalArray = new int[1];` with this: `int[] scoreTotalArray = new int[0];`

And in `btnAdd_Click`, switch the order of these two lines:
`scoreTotalArray[scoreCount] = score;`
`Array.Resize(ref scoreTotalArray, scoreTotalArray.Length + 1);`

Comment: You should probably also be using `scoreTotalArray.Length` instead of `scoreCount`. Remember the last item in an array is `array[array.Length - 1]`.

Comment: Thank you, did that, actually tried some of those things already, when I set it that way, and after I hit the "Clear Scores" button (after entering a few numbers) it clears them, but when I go to enter a new score and hit enter, I get an "out of bounds of the array"  error.  BUT it did get rid of the 0 at the top of the list.

Comment: Thanks a million, you guys(and or gals) are great help!!

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will definitely do that.  Thanks again :)